# Extraer la direccion de una imagen en pagina HTML con JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Estoy trabajando en este link: https://www.amazon.in/Google-Nexus-D821-16GB-Black/dp/B00GC1J55C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1421161258&sr=1-1&keywords=Google

En el div

```
<div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 514px;">
<img src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81KSpRuK0-L._SY741_.jpg" 
data-old-hires ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81KSpRuK0-L._SY741_.jpg">
</div>
```

Intente con el siguiente codigo, tanto usando en .attr el argumento "src" como "data-old-hires" y en ambos casos me imprime una linea vacia, Como lo puedo solucionar?

```
        Elements img = document.select("imgTagWrapper");
        String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
        System.out.println(imgSrc);
```

Comment: En el ```Elements img = document.select("imgTagWrapper");``` no deberías de poner si es un id o una clase? De este estilo: ```Elements img = document.select("#imgTagWrapper img");```

Comment: Justo acabo de hacerlo con `Element img = doc.getElementById("imgTagWrapper");` y luego cambie el "src" por "data-old-hires" y sucedio algo peculiar, La primera ejecucion funciono y mostro la url de la imagen, la segunda me Salio el mismo error de Java.lang.NullPointerException que me sale con el codigo original, Y probando tu apunte me sale tambien el error